# How to deploy a new version of a Google App Engine production server, without stopping old versions?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running a Google App Engine production server, using `basic_scaling` as the scale type. Whenever I update the code and deploy it - using `gcloud app deploy` - the old version of the code is shutdown.

[According to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown), that's expected:

> The shutdown process might be triggered by a variety of planned and unplanned events, such as:
>
> - You manually stop an instance.
> - **You deploy an updated version to the service.**
> - ...

I understand that it's easier for most developers that way. But in my case, I'd like to keep the old versions running until the `idle_timeout` limit is reached. Does anyone know if there's a way to avoid the automatic shutdown and let the old versions to shutdown by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--stop-previous-version), when you deploy your code, the default flag of `--stop-previous-version` is used. This forces the previous version to be stopped. If you do not want that, you should explicitly use the `--no-stop-previous-version` in your deploy command (we also have this as a feature on our [App, a GUI for GAE](https://nocommandline.com); you check or uncheck a checkbox).

Unfortunately, Google does not provide a way for the service to automatically shut down later. You'll have to manually shut it down and start the other version later.